# VPS　クラスタ　拡張の方法等　教えて頂けませんか？

Tags: hadoop

下記の様な facebookクローンを運用が前提です

Dolphin-v.7.3.3.1
elgg-2.3.3
friendica-develop
IsVipi-OSSN-master
mastodon-master
matcha-sns-1.3.8
oxwall-1.8.4.1
social_stream-master

LINEクローン的なspika4も想定しています。
http://isana.net/spika4business

VPS契約して、今後の拡張想定し
最初から クラスター設定しておくとして
途中から ダウンタイム0で出来るならそちらも......
方法があると助かります。

クラスターが適切だと思ったのですが
クラスターでは無い 良い方法があるならば
教えて頂けると幸いです。

仮想環境として OpenVZは
開発が完了していることから、KVMを選択

サーバーの最初の1台は下記のどれかを使い
拡張していく予定である。
KVM Linux 2 or KVM Linux 1 x2
time4vp

2コア / 2GB 50GB
https://www.kagoya.jp/cloud/vps/kvm.html#vps_header

今後 ストレージの増設 VPSの
増設・分散処理を容易に管理行う事を前提に

nginx webサーバー
Passenger rubyAPPサーバー
Tomcat JavaAPPサーバー
webデータ用ストレージクラスターを組むとして

データベースは
mariadb galera cluster
Hadoop Apache Spark 
Cassandra
併用として

統計データ計算に Platform Lavas等を
将来的には導入したい。

OSは Redhat系linuxを使いたい（centos7）

その場合 どうすれば 管理ツール含めて楽に運用出来るのか

構成含めて、一番効率的だと思われる方法もあれば
教えて頂けると幸いです。

下記等が よく使われている様ですが

Heartbeat + pacemaker + LXD+LXC
CentOS Atomic Host
libvirt qemu-kvm bridge-utils
wafは
ModSecurity Naxsi

今 何が運用が楽で、効率的で多機能で安全で
処理に問題ないのか？

以上 大変恐縮ですが、お知恵をお貸し頂ける方いれば
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/85332

Comment: まずはそれぞれのアプリケーションをサーバ1台で構築するところから初めてはいかがでしょうか。今の内容では要求される条件が明確でないので、具体的な回答をすることができない質問です。